# What desktop environment shoud I choose for VPS with 2GB RAM and 1v core 4800 BogoMIPS running Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: server, vpn, desktop-environments, vps

I have cheap VPS (2GB RAM, 1v core 4800 BogoMIPS, 20 GB SSD) with Ubuntu 22.04 on it, what desktop environment shoud I choose for it? Purpose of this VPS is VPN server (wireguard or openvpn) + doker. Any chances for good working desktop environment with this poor config?

Comment: Given you have only 2 GB RAM, you can try something like Antix instead of Ubuntu. https://antixlinux.com/download/. If you want to stick with Ubuntu then you can try Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi selection of operating systems is limited by VPS provider. So I stick with Ubuntu. I can't install Xubuntu or Lubuntu - no choice. Is it possible to install LXQt or  XFCE on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: You don't use a desktop with that (well you can but then using software like docker ... not likely) and 20Gb is probably also not going to be enough disk space. Docker will eat 1 Gb RAM =at least= so it will likely cripple your system. "VPN server" does not require a desktop; I would suggest using command line and manual editing.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to install either LXQt or Xfce on Ubuntu 22.04 that is running on a VPS that has only 2GB of RAM. For descriptions of these two metapackages run `apt show xfce4 lxqt`

Install metapackage for Xfce desktop environment:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xfce4
```

Install metapackage for LXQt:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lxqt
```